# Why Chinese character performance wrong in preg_replace function?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

My code is:

```
preg_replace('/[中]/', '1', '中，博文大，精中深');
```

Why the result is:

```
111，博文大，精111深
```

The Chinese character '中' should be replace once, while triple instead.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please read this article about [unicode characters in regexps](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).
Next, you may need this article about [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). I think that you need `u` modifier in your regexp.

```
preg_replace('/[中]/u', '1', '中，博文大，精中深');
```

Please, also read comments in [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) article for more examples.

Also, for simple replaces like in example above you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
str_replace('中', '1', '中，博文大，精中深');
```

Comment: It works.I know how to avoid it, but you help me figure it out essentially.Thank you very much.
Still a little question: why it replace or match three time without u modifier? Anyway, I know how to deal it in a right way.

Comment: I think trouble is in a fact that unicode characters are multibytes, so regexp can't understant that you want to replace all octets with your symbol and replaces each octet. But i'm not sure about it.